# Из JSON в <select>

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, json

Данные с обработчика приходят в JSON клиенту.

```
{"time_1030":"10:30","time_1035":"10:35","time_1040":"10:40","time_1045":"10:45","time_1050":"10:50","time_1055":"10:55" ... }
```

Как красиво запихнуть из в `select`? Чтобы конструкция была типа

```
<select>
<option value="time_1030">10:30</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

как-нибудь  так

```js
const data = {"time_1030":"10:30","time_1035":"10:35","time_1040":"10:40","time_1045":"10:45","time_1050":"10:50","time_1055":"10:55" };

$.each(data, function(k,v){ 
  $(`<option value="${k}">${v}</option>`).appendTo("select");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 const data = {
        "time_1030": "10:30",
        "time_1035": "10:35",
        "time_1040": "10:40",
        "time_1045": "10:45",
        "time_1050": "10:50",
        "time_1055": "10:55"
    };
    
function loadOptions(selectEl, data) {
        if (Object.keys(data).length) {
            for (let key in data) {
                let opt = document.createElement('option');
                opt.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data[key]));
                opt.value = key;
                selectEl.appendChild(opt);
            }
        }
    }

    let selectEl = document.getElementById('my_select');
    loadOptions(selectEl, data)
```

```html
<select id="my_select"></select>
```